# Can I use Node to add email functionality to an existing site?

Tags: node.js

I have a client with an existing straight up HTML/JavaScript site. No back end of any kind. He wants to add email functionality to it and I was thinking of using Node to do this for two reasons:

1. It seems like an extremely lightweight way to do it
2. He's talking about adding further functionality in the future.

What are the positives and negatives of this approach?

Comment: Off topic here.  Maybe webmasters.stackexchange

Comment: I disagree it being off-topic. It's a question about structure and design.

Comment: This looks fine here to me, too.

Answer (score 2):

Positive: Node is really cool and you'll feel really cool writing the code.

Negative: The appropriate solution would take 1/10th the time in PHP, Perl, or Python and one of those languages is probably already installed on the server. In addition, Node is still in beta.

Comment: node is not in beta.

Answer (score 0):

I gues you could use the [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs) plugin for node. Even if node wasn't serving the site you could still interact with node from the static webpage through websockets using [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

This all sounds a bit complicated but having been playing with node in the last week this stuff is amazingly easy to accomplish.